If I use the regularization method for feature selection and then use machine learning model to predict, am I overlapping?
I used the regularization method such as elastic-net as a feature selection and then I used the random forest and deep learning to predict the target using the selected features. The problem is classification. My colleague says that I'm overlapping!
I think is not overlapping because I considered just the selected features from elastic-net
apart from their importance. Am I correct?
